# How to set d:DesignInstance to a generic type?

Tags: generics, data-binding, datacontext

An easy one ;-)

I declared:

```
     xmlns:om="clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=System"
```

I try to set a generic as the DataType:

```
 <DataGrid d:DataContext="{
     d:DesignInstance Type=om:ObservableCollection&lt;System:Int32&gt;}" />
```

But I'm receiving an error: "Invalid format for a type".

Anybody have an idea how I can do that ?

Comment: Take a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637478/61434

Comment: @Revious, Wow, I think so! The H.B. answer seems very nice. Thanks you very much!!!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Generics are not supported yet.
We can derive a class from any generics and use that class instead.

**Oops, please see comment below from "Jan 'splite'K". It sounds that there is a markup extension that could do the job.**

**Also, look at uli78 link**

**Update 2021-09-30** , I think a great answer is given here: [How do I set WPF xaml form's Design DataContext to class that uses generic type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235421/how-do-i-set-wpf-xaml-forms-design-datacontext-to-class-that-uses-generic-type) (thanks to Revious for its comment)

Comment: Hello from 5 years later, still not supported YET! :) For random googler like me, there is [markup extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8235459/628532)

Answer (score 8):

You could try this:

```
<DataGrid d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type={x:Type om:ObservableCollection`1}}" />
```

Comment: This actually works, though I have no idea why :-)