# Fill dictionary with sampledata

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary

How do I fill a dictionary with sampledata to use in design mode?

I added `xmlns:k="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"` to be able to add key-value pairs but somehow it still doesnt work.

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: You should consider using Expression Blend.  It has some nice tools for generating sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no proper support for generic class in XAML (in XAML 2009 there is [`x:TypeArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750476.aspx), currently only usable in uncompiled XAML), a workaround is using custom markup extensions that create them via reflection. An example can be found in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8235459/546730) of mine, you could adjust it for dictionaries so you can also add the key value pairs.