# d:DesignInstance with an interface type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resharper

I'm binding an UI to an interface (which is implemented by several presenters, not accessible from the UI assembly).

I really like d:DesignInstance in designer because it (kind of) makes xaml strongly typed using R#.

Sadly, d:DesignInstance does not support interface types: "Cannot create an instance of an interface."

[image: Design instance on interface]

The first thing I thought is: Ok, no problem, let's create a custom markup extension which takes a System.Type as parameter, and which ProvideValue method returns a fake instance of it (dummy implementation of this interface, generated by dynamic IL emission).

This works quite well, bindings are resolved at design-time (I can see that in the design panel since my markup extension fills the object properties with a lorem-ipsum)

**BUT** the nicest R# feature dont work: Resharper does not recognize datacontext type, and just gives a message "Cannot resolve property '{0}' in data context of type 'object'"

[image: Custom markup extension]

Does someone know how to fix this ?

(any alternative which would allow me to let R# know about an interface datacontext type would be great)

Thanks !

***ps:*** I also tried to create another markup extension which returns the generated runtime type in order to give it to DesignInstance: "{d:DesignInstance Type={utilsUi:InstanceType commons:User}}"  => Gives the error "Object of type 'InstanceType' cannot be converted to type 'System.Type'"
... seems that DesignInstance does not support inner markup extensions :(

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio and Resharper? In 2012, I don't get the "Cannot create an instance of an interface" message and Resharper Intellisense works, but not in 2010. Also `IsDesignTimeCreatable=False` does not solve the issue in 2010.

Comment: @nmclean: That is quite surprising, i'm using as well VS 2012 with resharper 8 ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just investigated more or less the same question... Actually, what I did is to follow the principles of [MvvMLight](http://www.mvvmlight.net/). Precisely, I used a ViewModelLocator (which will be more or less static) so that the "right" ViewModel is injected at runtime or at design time. The magic lies in the function *ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic* provided by the MvvMLight framework. Finally, my *ViewModelLocator* class looks like

```
public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        private static readonly IKernel _kernel;

        static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            _kernel = new StandardKernel();
            if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            {
                 _kernel.Bind<IBasicVM>().To<DesignBasicVm>();
            }
            else
            {
                _kernel.Bind<IBasicVM>().To<BasicVm>();
            }
        }

        public IBasicVM BasicVm { get { return _kernel.Get<IBasicVM>(); } }
    }
```

You may ignore the [Ninject](http://ninject.codeplex.com/) *_kernel* but you may need it (or a similar Ioc) if you are building your ViewModels with an IoC.

The App.xaml declares the *ViewModelLocator* as a ressource

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <viewModel:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

The *MainWindow.DataContext* property is bound to the *BasicVM* member of the *ViewModelLocator*. The Text property is bound the the *GetContent* member of the interface *IBasicVM* which is recognized statically by R# (at least R# 7.1 with VS2012)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        DataContext="{Binding BasicVm, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"
        >
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding GetContent}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You may check [this repository](https://github.com/bpatra/DesignableMVVMSample) which I have created as a template.

Answer (score 44):

I've found out how it's possible to overcome this illogical Visual Studio XAML designer error.

Instead of

```
<SomeControl d:DataContext={d:DesignInstance commons:IUser}>
    <!--element content here-->
</SomeControl>
```

You can write

```
<SomeControl>
    <d:SomeControl.DataContext>
        <x:Type Type="commons:IUser" />
    </d:SomeControl.DataContext>
    <!--element content here-->
</SomeControl>
```

Yes, this solution doesn't look as cool but definitely it isn't much worse.

`Type` tag allows specifying interfaces, nested types (e.g. n:A+B) and even generics!

In case of generics just add a backtick and number of type arguments to your type: `` <x:Type Type="commons:User`1" /> ``.

BTW all of these also works with styles, `<d:Style.DataContext>` doesn't produce errors!

Comment: best answer by far, i found it while looking for a way to avoid errors in styles. no downsides (except that it's a bit more verbose), plus being able to specify interfaces (and generics) is HUGE.

Comment: I realize that this is an old answer, but it's by far the best answer I've found on this subject.  I am wondering, though: when you say "nested types," do you mean multiple types?  And if so, how do you implement multiple types?  When I try `<x:Type Type="commons:IUser+IFoo"/>` from your example, I get an error saying that no such interface exists (because it's looking for one called `IUser+IFoo`).  Using the `commons:` prefix for the second interface doesn't fix it.  Obviously, the `DataContext` property can't be set twice, so having two `<x:Type/>` lines doesn't work.

Comment: @ElizaBennet By "nested type" I mean a nested class/interface, i. e. the one that was declared *inside* another class. For example, if you have `public class User { public class Foo { } }`, then in XAML you can specify type of `Foo` as `<x:Type Type="yournamespace:User+Foo"/>`. As for the second part of the question, unfortunately, you cannot provide multiple types to `x:Type` simultaneously, as `x:Type` is a `MarkupExtension`, and to retrieve actual `Type` object it represents WPF calls its `ProvideValue` method, which return type is exactly `Type`, *not* an array of types or something else.

Comment: Well, the return type of `ProvideValue` is `object`, but MSDN says that for `TypeExtension` it always returns values of type `Type` :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.typeextension?view=netframework-4.7

Comment: Is there a way to inherit it from a base style? I found I have to copy those 3 lines in all my controls and can't put it in the base one. :/

Comment: Wouldn't that just make that data context a Type object?

Comment: d:DesignInstance is used to define the outline of the data context object, so that bindings can be auto-completed and validated at design time. d:DataContext doesn't do that, and even if, "TypeExtension" or "Type" do not have the properties my ViewModel has, so all bindings show a warning "No XYZ property in type 'TypeExtension'." So how's defining a `Type` object as `DataContext` going to help with defining `MyViewModel<T>` as `DesignInstance`?

Answer (score 20):

You can take advantage of IsDesignTimeCreatable in this case like so:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance commons:User, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
```

which essentially instructs the designer to only use the type for intellisense and error highlighting instead of actually trying to instantiate a design instance.

Comment: Not the good answer (I already knew about IsDesignTimeCreatable and it does not suit my needs), but i'm awarding you not to waste the bounty :) thx for answering

Comment: Just add 'd:' to second parameter and it will work fine: DataContext="{d:DesignInstance commons:User, d:IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"

Comment: Doesn't help. Isn't IsDesignTimeCreatable false by default?

Comment: still cannot use an interface

Answer (score -1):

@Olivier: This is one of the best scenarios where you can make use of "Adapter Design Pattern"

Note: I have no idea on Resharper, I am a C# & .NET developer. but I understand there is compatibility problem based on your explanation.
below is the possible solution that you can try.

1. Write one C# class that implement the Interface type you need.
2. Implement the interface in the class however do not write the entire implementation on your own. instead call the other class methods that implement the interface within the implemented methods.
3. start using the class that you have written.
4. the class that you have written to get the compatibility is known as Adapter.

sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create an object of your adapter class and consume the features.
        AdapterInterfaceUI obj = new AdapterInterfaceUI();

        // Even though you have written an adapter it still performs the operation in base class
        // which has the interface implementation and returns the value.
        // NOTE : you are consuming the interface but the object type is under your control as you are the owner of the adapter class that you have written.
        Console.WriteLine(obj.DisplayUI());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}


#region code that might be implemented in the component used.
public interface IinterfaceUI
{
    string DisplayUI();
}

public class ActualUI : IinterfaceUI
{
    //Factory pattern that would be implemented in the component that you are consuming.
    public static IinterfaceUI GetInterfaceObject()
    { 
        return new ActualUI();
    }

    public string DisplayUI()
    {
        return "Interface implemented in ActualUI";
    }
}
#endregion


#region The adapter class that you may need to implement in resharper or c# which ever works for you.
public class AdapterInterfaceUI : ActualUI, IinterfaceUI
{
    public string DisplayUI()
    {
        return base.DisplayUI();
    }
}
#endregion
```

I think this solution will help you out.

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for. I dont want to polute my assemblies (which are redistributed) with bunches of useless design classes. Nor to spend time implementing those. thanks anyway

Comment: ps: Resharper is just a visual studio extension.